# using Vue class component in another Vue class component (Vue JS 2)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component

I have page that uses 2 components (Navbvar.vue and ContentPost.vue).

Here's my Navbar.vue Component

```
<script lang="ts">
import Axios from 'axios';
import Vue from 'vue';
import Component from 'vue-class-component';
import {
    UserPrivilegeSettingsService,
    InboxService
} from '../../services/NSwagService';
import { PostApprovalService } from '../../services/Ishare/PostApprovalService';


@Component({
    created: async function(this: Navbar) {
        await this.getpage();
        await this.initialize();
    },
    props: ['role'],
    watch: {
        waitingForApproval: function(this: Navbar){
            console.log("inside watcher")
            console.log(this.waitingForApproval)
        }
    }
})
export default class Navbar extends Vue {
    api: UserPrivilegeSettingsService = new UserPrivilegeSettingsService();
    page: string[] = [];
    employeeRole : any = {};
    async getpage() {
        var data = await this.api.pageAccess();
        this.page = data;
    }

    //12/20/2019 - 10:15 tetep di show navbar menunya walau tidak ada content

    InboxService: InboxService = new InboxService();
    UnreadInbox: number = 0;

    roles: Array<string> = ['Dealer HO']

    // Computed
    get currentRouteName() {
        return window.location.pathname;
    }
    
    //admin KMM user privelege
    PostApprovalService: PostApprovalService = new PostApprovalService();
    userPrivelegeAdminKMM: string = "";
    bubblePostWaitingForApproval: any = {};
    waitingForApproval: number = 0;

    async initialize() {
        this.UnreadInbox = await this.InboxService.getUnreadInboxCount();
        this.employeeRole = await this.getEmployeeRole();
        this.userPrivelegeAdminKMM = await this.PostApprovalService.GetUserPrivilege(); 
        this.employeeRole = this.employeeRole.data
        if (this.employeeRole === null) {
            this.employeeRole = {
                isTamPeople : true
            }
        }
        if(this.userPrivelegeAdminKMM == 'Dealer Instructor'){
            this.bubblePostWaitingForApproval = await this.getBubblePostWaitingForApproval();
        }
    }

    async getEmployeeRole() {
        const url = '/api/v1/user-role/get-user-login-role'
        return Axios.get(url)
    }

    async getBubblePostWaitingForApproval() {
        if(this.userPrivelegeAdminKMM == 'Dealer Instructor'){
            this.bubblePostWaitingForApproval = await this.PostApprovalService.GetBubblePostWaitingForApproval();
            this.waitingForApproval = this.bubblePostWaitingForApproval.postWaitingForApproval;
        }
    }

    minusBubble(){
        this.waitingForApproval--;
    }

    // Function & Method
    rotateIcon(menu: string) {
        const rotate = document.getElementById('collapse-icon-' + menu);
        const isRotate = rotate.style.transform;
        if (rotate.classList.contains('rotate-icon')) {
            rotate.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
            if (isRotate === 'rotate(0deg)') {
                rotate.style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)';
            }
        } else {
            if (isRotate === 'rotate(-90deg)') {
                rotate.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
            } else {
                rotate.style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)';
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to trigger **waitingForApproval** property through ContentPost.vue Component, I tried this way inside ContentPost.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
import Navbar from '../Layout/Navbar.vue'
@Component({
        props: [],
        created: async function (this: Approval) {
            this.isBusy = true;
            var currenMonth: number = this.currentDate.getMonth();
            var currentYear: number = this.currentDate.getFullYear();

            this.startDateFilter = new Date(currentYear, currenMonth, 1);
            this.endDateFilter = new Date(new Date(currentYear, currenMonth+1, 1).setDate(new Date(currentYear, currenMonth+1, 1).getDate() - 1));
            this.startDateBarchart = this.startDateFilter;
            this.endDateBarchart = this.endDateFilter;
            this.search.startDate = moment(this.startDateFilter).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            this.search.endDate = moment(this.endDateFilter).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            await this.fetchdataUserIdentifier();

            if(this.userIdentifier != "Dealer Instructor"){
                await this.fetchdataReported();
                await this.getApprovalStatusContentPost();
            } else {
                await this.fetchdataWaitingForApproval();
                await this.fetchdataReportedTakenDown();
            }

            // const params = window.location.search;
            // const getParam = new URLSearchParams(params);
            // this.search.keywords = getParam.get('keyword');

            await this.fetchdata();

            this.isBusy = false;
        }
    })
export default class Approval extends Vue {
    Navbar: Navbar = new Navbar();
    async resetAfterApproval(){
        this.search.pageIndex = 1;
        this.allData.data = [];
        this.allData.totalData = 0;
        this.fetchdata();
        this.fetchdataWaitingForApproval();
        this.fetchdataReportedTakenDown();
        this.fetchdataReported();
        this.getApprovalStatusContentPost();
        this.Navbar.minusBubble();
        // window.location.href = `/IShare/ContentPost`
    }
}
</script>
```

the console.log inside the Navbar.vue Component is triggered and the value of **waitingForApproval** changes but the value in the html inside Navbar.vue template won't change, why?

Here is my html template in Navbar.vue

```
<span v-if="userPrivelegeAdminKMM == 'Dealer Instructor' && waitingForApproval != 0">Content Post <span class="bubble-post-waiting-for-approval">{{ waitingForApproval }}</span></span>
```